# RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, faiss

My code:

```py
chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=vectorIndex.as_retriever())
chain
query = "what is the price of Tiago iCNG?"

langchain.debug=True

input_data = {"question": query}
result = chain(input_data, return_only_outputs=True)
```

I get this error:

```
[chain/error] [1:chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain > 3:chain:MapReduceDocumentsChain] [8.64s] Chain run errored with error:
"IndexError('list index out of range')"
[chain/error] [1:chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain] [8.68s] Chain run errored with error:
"IndexError('list index out of range')"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-154a1fc94a62> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 
      6 input_data = {"question": query}
----> 7 result = chain(input_data, return_only_outputs=True)

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/schema/output_parser.py in parse_result(self, result, partial)
    224             Structured output.
    225         """
--> 226         return self.parse(result[0].text)
    227 
    228     @abstractmethod

IndexError: list index out of range`your text`
```

I want to call a llms api googlepalm and given the some url and convert the vectorembedding and store the faiss vectordatabase then use langchian and call the chain the given the new query.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags. You might also want to take a look at the [guide on formatting with markdown](/help/markdown).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your code you're trying to either return or print out your "results". If so one of the issues might be that you need to call the function invoke and then pass in the input data variable you have. So something like

```
chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=vectorIndex.as_retriever())
chain
query = "what is the price of Tiago iCNG?"

langchain.debug=True

input_data = {"question": query}
result = chain.invoke(input_data)
```

Alternatively, you can simply the last line to something like

```
result = chain.invoke(query)
```